# eliminate blank cells in excel when extracting data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two worksheets. One is where the user type in the data and the other is where it gets automatically summarize the data in matrix. the problem is I don't want blank cells in the matrix when data gets retrieved.

Is there any way this can be done?

In the matrix I have 36 columns and 65 rows and not all will be filled because it depends on the criteria that the user will give.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Pivot Table to summarize the data. Setupthe Table based on current input data.  As records are added/deleted/edited, the Table can be refreshed .